# Get-Content of file without Extension

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

Working with some Windows 10 computers in my environment and looking to make a quick PowerShell script to edit a config file for our IM program.

Some quick googling to tweak my script had it working great for my test file. It's possibly not the most graceful solution, but it was working so I decided to give it the green light. Just to find out that `Get-Content` couldn't find my config file because it does not have an extension.

Here's my script:

```
(Get-Content "$env:USERPROFILE\AppData\Roaming\Config") | Foreach-Object {
    $_ -replace '^autoawaytime = [0-9]+',("autoawaytime = 9")
} | Foreach-Object {
    $_ -replace '^autoaxtime = [0-9]+',("autoaxtime = 99")
} | Set-Content ("$env:USERPROFILE\AppData\Roaming\Config")
```

And the error;

```
Get-Content : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Config' because it
does not exist.
At C:\Users\\Desktop\textFileEdit.ps1:1 char:2
+ (Get-Content "$env:USERPROFILE\AppData\Roaming\Config" | Select BaseN ...
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\bretb\AppData\Roaming\Config:String) [Get-Content], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
```

So from this I concluded that the problem is that my config file lacks a file extension and `Get-Content` does not like that. Could someone propose how I can `Get-Content` on my config file, or perhaps propose a more elegant solution for me?

Comment: I don't believe you have the right path. Generally the path is `'%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Company\Product\ExecutableName.Config `

Comment: My goodness. That is embarrassing. You are correct. I forgot the \Product\ folder. If you put that down as an answer, I'll tag you as the right answer. Thanks

Comment: lol, @bbetnar! We all do it every once and while. Answer provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, it looks like path to the config file is not correct.

The common path should be something like

> %userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Company\Product\ExecutableName.Config